# Having trouble structuring tensorflow model class

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

I am having some trouble figuring out how to structure my Tensorflow model code. I having been following the guidelines on this site: [link](https://danijar.com/structuring-your-tensorflow-models/).

However, with this structure, I realized that I am unable to declare my model in such a way that I can pass the training data in  the Model class's `train()` method.

**train() method**:

```
def train(self, data_x, data_y):
    seq_length, longest_seq, data_x = Utils.padding(data_x)
    n_inputs = np.array(data_x).shape[0]

    self.x_placeholder_input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, longest_seq, n_inputs])
    self.y_placeholder_label = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[None, self.num_of_classes])
    self.sq_placeholder_seq_length = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[None])

    num_of_epoch = 100
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        for epoch in range(num_of_epoch):
            # initialise all variables
            sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
            sess.run(self.optimize(),
                     feed_dict={self.x_placeholder_input: data_x,
                                self.y_placeholder_label: data_y,
                                self.sq_placeholder_seq_length: seq_length})

            if num_of_epoch % 10 == 0:
                # Create Saver to save model
                print "Cycle " + str(epoch) + " out of " + str(num_of_epoch) + " done"
                saver = tf.train.Saver()
                location = saver.save(sess, "saved_models/model")
                print "Model saved to : " + str(location)
```

**Model class's __init__() method**:

```
def __init__(self, num_of_classes):
    # placeholders
    self.x_placeholder_input
    self.y_placeholder_label
    self.sq_placeholder_seq_length

    self.num_of_classes = num_of_classes
```

My original plan of execution is that I create an instance of Model class in a separate **main.py** script. After that depending on the mode (prediction/training). Only then, I will pass the training data over to the model via `train()`.

Since the training_data contains data (text files) of different steps, I will need the data before being able to determine the shapes of the placeholders. (It is similar to the **Setting the sequence lengths** section of this example:[link](https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml/blob/master/14_recurrent_neural_networks.ipynb))

Thus with my current implementation, I am forced to only create the model instance after the mode is chosen(prediction/training), which I find inefficient as switching from training --> prediction, prediction --> training will create multiple model instances.

So am I structuring the code wrongly or my original execution plan is not normal/conventional?

Current full code for model class(If it helps, if more is needed, let me know): [link](https://gist.github.com/duemaster/cf76bc023a9ce02b661dbd6067a19472)

Comment: Why can't you move the input  placeholders from train to init, and let both train and predict use it?

Comment: @vijaym Because I am unable to determine the size of input placeholders due to inputs having different steps. Hence, I need to wait for the data first, then initialize the placeholders.

Comment: Any reason why you were unable to determine the size of input placeholders?. In RNNs even though the sequence may have different length, we need to pad it to a fixed  size and then use it.

Comment: @vijaym . You are right about the padding. However, from what I understand about RNN so far, I need to pad it to the  longest length, hence, I need to get the entire dataset to get the max length.

Comment: but you process the dataset offline and calculate the max length. U don't do it during training.

Comment: @vijaym so I don't pass it the data during training? (i.e pass data as an argument in `train()`)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148565/discussion-between-vijay-m-and-coding-noobie).